# How is a shellscript syntax checker invoked (by/with syntastic and pathogen)?

Tags: bash, vim, static-analysis, shellcheck, bashate

When I work on a bash/sh script, pathogen kicks in and correctly loads everything that's in `~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/sh/`. I checked with `:scriptnames` in command-line mode. Included are `shellcheck.vim`, `checkbashism.vim`, `bashate.vim` etc.

Starting a vim session `filetype` is correctly detected and the corresponding bundled syntax-checking scripts are loaded.

But how does syntastic invoke `/usr/bin/shellcheck` or `bashate` or `checkbashism`?  There is nothing immediately obvious for it in `~/.vimrc`.

Can more than one syntax checker be invoked at the same time? E.g. can `shellcheck` AND `bashate` work alongside one another? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the downvote ! If I wrote something very wrong or in  a wrong manner, I would like to know. If on that basis my question needs editing it can be done. But downvoting without giving the faintest of a reason is simply useless. It does not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only role of pathogen in your setup is to append the path and subpaths of each of your plugins to the `'runtimepath'` option when Vim starts up. Nothing more, nothing less.

As for Syntastic, [the default checkers](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim#L88) for shell scripts are [`sh`](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/syntax_checkers/sh/sh.vim) and [`shellcheck`](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/syntax_checkers/sh/shellcheck.vim). Read `:help syntastic-checker-options` to learn how to define your own list of checkers.

Comment: +1 I knew the role of `pathogen` explicitly stated on its home page. The result is obvious with `:scriptnames`. I also had seen the extensive list of syntax checkers covered by Syntastic from its wiki and by doing `$ tree -L 4 ~/.vim `. What I hadn't see is by the code you include. That is my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Cbhihe You should never, ever, rely on the default lists of checkers.  These default lists are more trouble then they're worth, and are likely to go away completely in a future version.  You should always define `g:syntastic_*_checkers` to suit your needs.  You don't need to look at the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

From what romainl only linked to ([the relevant parts of links should be quoted when answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)):

> You can tell syntastic which checkers to run for a given filetype by setting a variable 'g:syntastic__checkers' to a list of checkers, e.g.
>
> `let g:syntastic_php_checkers = ["php", "phpcs", "phpmd"]`

As for your question about invocation: according to [the FAQ](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic#faqargs), the "command line is constructed using an internal function named `makeprgBuild()`, which provides a number of options that allow you to customise every part of the command that gets run. You can set these options using global variables". ([See this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10013).)